# About prototyping concept in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In the code below, I have class called Foo and I add a prototype called data which is an array, and I add a function called showData as a prototype to the class.

```
var Foo = function (name) 
{ 
   this.name = name; 
};
Foo.prototype.data = [1, 2, 3]; // setting a non-primitive property
Foo.prototype.showData = function () 
{ 
  console.log(this.name, this.data); 
};
```

The question is, is there a difference if I define data and showData inside the Foo class as:

```
 var Foo = function (name) 
    { 
       this.name = name; 
       this.data = [1, 2, 3];
       this.showData = function () 
       { 
          console.log(this.name, this.data); 
        };
    };
```

Comment: `console.log( Foo )` and compare the differences! :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's a major difference.

In the first case, the `data` array is shared by all instance of `Foo`. So if you modify the property of one instances, all are modified :

```
var f1 = new Foo(),
    f2 = new Foo();
f2.data[2] = 4; // also changes f1.data
```

It also consumes less memory due to this sharing but that's probably not your concern apart if you create many instances of `Foo` (note that in JS, as often in gc based languages consuming memory, isn't only bad because of the memory consumption but because of the CPU used to garbage it).

But setting properties to `prototype` is tricky, as the search always starts from the childest element : if you set `f2.data = [1,2,4]`, then you change `f2.data` but you don't change `f1.data` (this produces 2 different arrays).

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference is that, by adding properties to the prototype, you're adding them to all instances of `Foo`, even those already created.

Your second version also involves executing those additional lines of code **every time** a `new Foo` is instantiated, which can be a potentially *huge* amount of overhead.